# Action bars before Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Before Android introduced Action Bars in Honeycomb, was a typical navigation bar just a linear layout that was placed at the top of an activity layout and contained the buttons to handle whatever request the app provided? I'm just wondering bcause I can't seem to find any official doc from google about creating a navigation menu before Honeycomb came out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. Who ever there are ways to implement Actionbar on earlier version aswell with support package.
I myself use Actionbar sherlock that is one of the best ways if you ask me

Here is a link to Actionbar Sherlock http://actionbarsherlock.com/

And a tutorial if you want some help starting http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.se/2013/04/action-bar-sherlock-action-bar-with.html

Answer (score 1):

android has given a v4, v7, v13 package support. Putting those packages in your application, you can use those features in api level below 13.

Have a lokk at this link:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: Yep I know. I still wanted to know if that was how action bars were implemented back then.